# How to find where in a large expression Power::infy is generated?

Tags: expression-manipulation, searching

Consider the following expression:

```
With[{h = 21, z = 22}, 
    (Integrate[(ω^(h + 1) Sqrt[1 - ω^2]^(z - 1))/ Sqrt[2 + M ω^2] *
        Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -((h + z)/2), 3/2, (M ω^2)/(2 + M ω^2)]
    , ω] /. 
    ArcSin[k_ ω]/ω :> k) /. ω -> 0]
```

I deliberately try to avoid using `Limit`, since it'll be too slow (I have lots of values for `h` and `z` and need the calculation to take reasonable time). The expression as it is now leads to a bunch of `Power::infy` messages. I'm trying to find the most common cases of `0/0` indeterminancies to eliminate manually (as I did for `ArcSin[kx]/x` above). But the expression is too large to be processed by a human mind.

So my question is: how can I find *the exact place* where division by zero occurs? I found the case with `ArcSin` by chance, having found a zero in denominator in stack trace for the `Power::infy` message. But is there a way to search for a zero in denominator of a held expression automatically?

Comment: If you want to look at `w=0`, I guess you can use `Series[]`.

Comment: @AnjanKumar I'm not sure how `Series` is more helpful than `Limit` in this case...

Comment: Please provide an example that gives an error message.  I get zero for an answer with no error messages, whether or not I include 'ArcSin[k_ ω]/ω :> k`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey well the example in the OP gives me errors and `Indeterminate` at the end with Mathematica 11.0. Sometimes it stops emitting errors and gives zero until you restart the Kernel.

Comment: With `$Version` "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)", I reproducibly obtain `0` without error messages.  Precisely what version are you using?  There may be a bug here.

Comment: @bbgodfrey 11.0.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (July 28, 2016). I guess I have to update.

Comment: Please share with the community the outcome of updating, especially if the problem does not go away.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey the same result with 11.0.1 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (September 21, 2016). Just copied and pasted the code from the question and got the errors. See [the screenshot from 11.0.1 and 11.0.0](http://6g6.eu/sih-2-screenshot-110217-112755-png).

Comment: Perhaps, you should tag this as a bug.

Comment: @bbgodfrey strangely, I've easily reproduced it on Windows 10 with the same version as yours. And in fact I've found where the division by zero occurs: it's in a large polynomial, which appears in denominator and doesn't have a shifting constant. I'm not sure though why it doesn't always result in this. May be related to performance of the PC on which the code is run, so that `Integrate` does more/fewer simplifications in process, which removes the removable singularity. At least I know that `Simplify` does depend on PC performance, maybe `Integrate` too...

Comment: With `$Version` "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)", and the code in your question, I obtained a set of error messages, the first being, `power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered`.  I then reran the computation with "11.0.1" and obtained an answer of `0` with no error messages.  Note that I have a quite robust PC with 16 GB memory.  By the way, did your Windows 10 computation use 64 bits?  In any case, I recommend that you flag this as a bug and report it.